# Implement getDirection in google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a marker on a predefined location .What I want is to get the direction to that marker from my current location which I get from the GPS.
I tried many SO links but they didn't help as there were only few links for Google maps v2. It would be wonderful if I get some updated tutorial or code snippets  of the same .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this example i think it suits your requirement [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can check this guide I wrote as well:

[Guide: Google Maps V2 for Android: Draw Driving Direction on Map](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful to you ; )